# How to play audio in iOS in background?

Tags: codenameone

My goal is to make iOS play audio in a background.

When the audio is received by iPhone, it's not played unless I open the app in the foreground.
Basically, the iPhone is "waiting" when I click to open the app, and then it plays the audio.

Following Developer Guide, I added `ios.background_modes=music` to my .properties file.
However, nothing changed in behaviour.

I receive audio in real time via websocket class (`onMessage(byte[] message)` method).

What approach would you suggest in order to resolve this issue and make iOS play audio in a background?

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax for adding via the GUI not editing the properties file directly. You need to add the property with a `codename1.arg.` prefix.

Specifically: `codename1.arg.ios.background_modes=music`

Comment: Sorry that I didn't specify in the original question, but this is exactly how I added the hint to the properties. The result is the same as without having this hint.

Comment: Now I noticed you play via websocket. This is a problem because iOS detects that as networking which you shouldn't do. You need to play musing via HTTPS or via file system for the background behavior to fall under the "music" option. Apple is very strict on these things.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. I'll look deeper into it.